# Spring boot 2.1 while loading external properties, application properties in classpath are ignored

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, properties-file

I am having an application.properties in my main/resources folder. Now certain values I want to over-ride at runtime using an external properties file.
To do this I have added the following code:

```
class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            application=application.properties('spring.config.location:/external/properties/,${catalina.base}/../config/config.properties')
    application.build()
    application.sources(Application)
 }
}
```

With this change its reading the external file but completely ignoring the application.properties file (i.e any value present in application.properties only is not retained).

- Spring boot version : 2.1.0.RELEASE
- Groovy version : 2.5.3
- JDK : 1.8

Note : This same code was working for spring boot version 1.5.10.RELEASE

Comment: Plz check, dual data source example in  o7planning tutorial . Hope it will help

Comment: @Pradejo I think that article is tackling a different problem.